# Why document.createElement('br') from json file is not visible

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to adjust the json-hero tutorial file from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON. I do not need a li list of "powers". I want to display it like a short text with line breaks.
I replaced document.createElement('li') with document.createElement('br'). Why document.createElement('br') from .json file (superheroes.json) is not displayed and is hidden only? (If document.createElement('p') is used for replacement it is displayed OK.)
https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json
Here is the script:

```
 <script>
    const header = document.querySelector('header');
    const section = document.querySelector('section');

    let requestURL = 'superheroes.json';
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', requestURL);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();

    request.onload = function() {
      const superHeroes = request.response;
      populateHeader(superHeroes);
      showHeroes(superHeroes);
    }

    function populateHeader(obj) {
      const myH1 = document.createElement('h1');
      myH1.textContent = obj['squadName'];
      header.appendChild(myH1);

      const myPara = document.createElement('p');
      myPara.textContent = 'Hometown: ' + obj['homeTown'] + ' // Formed: ' + obj['formed'];
      header.appendChild(myPara);
    }

    function showHeroes(obj) {
      const heroes = obj['members'];

      for(let i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {
        const myArticle = document.createElement('article');
        const myH2 = document.createElement('h2');
        const myPara1 = document.createElement('p');
        const myPara2 = document.createElement('p');
        const myPara3 = document.createElement('p');
        //const myList = document.createElement('ul'); > replaced by:
        const myDiv = document.createElement('div');

        myH2.textContent = heroes[i].name;
        myPara1.textContent = 'Secret identity: ' + heroes[i].secretIdentity;
        myPara2.textContent = 'Age: ' + heroes[i].age;
        myPara3.textContent = 'Superpowers:';

        const superPowers = heroes[i].powers;
        var x = "";
        for(let j = 0; j < superPowers.length; j++) {
            
          //const listItem = document.createElement('li');  > replaced by br
          //problem - the following is hidden and not displayed:
          const newlineItem = document.createElement('br');
          
          newlineItem.textContent = superPowers[j];
          myDiv.appendChild(newlineItem);
        }

        myArticle.appendChild(myH2);
        myArticle.appendChild(myPara1);
        myArticle.appendChild(myPara2);
        myArticle.appendChild(myPara3);
//content of myDiv is hidden - why?        
myArticle.appendChild(myDiv);
        section.appendChild(myArticle);
      }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: `<br>` tags don’t have content. What do you expect `newlineItem.textContent = superPowers[j];` to do?

Comment: You do `newlineItem.textContent = superPowers[j];` but that doesn't result in valid DOM content. It should produce `<br>some text</br>`, however that's not really possible.

Comment: [`br`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br#Technical_summary) is an empty element, it can't contain any content.

Comment: I wan just to display the text with line breaks

Comment: Why not use a `div` then? Notice, that you can style a `div` to behave more like a `li`, just set some margin to it with CCS.

Comment: Div did the job - good idea, thanks. Is any solution to get classic text formatting text< br > text < br > text?

Comment: Sure, just [create a textnode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode), append it to `myDiv`, and create a `br` element and append it to `myDiv`.

Comment: @Idigest That would be `myDiv.append("text", document.createElement("br"), "text", document.createElement("br"), "text")`. Three [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) nodes and two [`HTMLBRElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLBRElement)s. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thanks Teemu - it seems working by this way: 
for(let j = 0; j < superPowers.length; j++) {
var t = document.createTextNode(superPowers[j]);
myDiv.appendChild(t);
const linebreak = document.createElement('br');
myDiv.appendChild(linebreak);
}

Answer (score 0):

You encounter this problem because br tags don't show on the screen, if you inspect your code you should be seeing something like `<br>Content of superPowers[j]</br>` but it isn't visible in you screen.

To get the result you want you can try and change the br tag with p tag (if you want to go back to the next line in the next superPower), or with span tag (if you want to put your superPowers in the same line).

Your code should look like this:

```
//each element in a new line method
const newlineItem = document.createElement('p');
newlineItem.textContent = superPowers[j];
myDiv.appendChild(newlineItem);

//same line method
const newlineItem = document.createElement('span');
newlineItem.textContent = superPowers[j];
myDiv.appendChild(newlineItem);
```

Comment: Thanks, I need the new line method - div instead of span would by better as Teemu proposed in comments.